# put transparency everything except div

Tags: html, click, transparency

I'm trying to find a way to put some transparency in everything except one div. And just to allow to click on that specific div. This probably is a easy question but I'm really out of ideas where to find the answer. I think this could be something like the modal dialog effect... but with my specific div...

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it was tagged jQuery

```
$('#fields input:not(#the_one_field_to_stay_active)').attr('disabled');
$('#fields textarea:not(#the_one_field_to_stay_active)').attr('disabled');
$('#fields *:not(#the_one_field_to_stay_active)').click(function() {return false});
$('#fields *:not(#the_one_field_to_stay_active)').css({opacity: 0.8});
```

Comment: hi kyle... I'm not understanding this explanation but thanks anyway. Later I'm going to get back to the problem and then I'll try your reply..

Comment: The first two lines disable all input fields and textareas except the one you want active. The third disables any anchor tags and the fourth makes all the disabled elements semi-transparent

Comment: Indubitably. To see if you were paying attention

Comment: thanks Kyle... It worked perfect! I wasn't changing the #fields with a correct div id so I wasn't getting it. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

Try [jquery overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html). It should meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery. You can do with CSS alone.

My answer here should solve your problem:

[CSS suppress screen like Javascript alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8860116/css-suppress-screen-like-javascript-alert/8860240#8860240)

Create a div with position: fixed that is 100% height and width. Then set the background either to rbga(255,255,255,.8) or a repeating 1px square white opaque png (either with the opacity of your choice). Having a div overlay content with an opaque white background gives the same effect as lowering the actual opacity on the underlying content.

Comment: thanks j-man... nice post! I'll test it and then give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

This is built into jQuery UI so you shouldn't need to use any extra plugins.  Just include the UI file along with jQuery.  And replace the word "jQuery" with a "$".  Make sure the argument value you pass for the "obj" parameter is the id of your div tag.  Notice we're referencing a page for "dData" so if you have to re-use this dialog, or is shared, you can re-use it.  But that can be changed if you prefer to have the data defined in another way.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>

// dTitle - title of the modal dialog being displayed
// dWidth - width as a fraction of 1 relative to the width of the window
// dHeight - height as a fraction of 1 relative to the height of the window
// dData - the URL and query string of the page being requested within the object tag
// obj - id of <div> tag
// objType - type of object (ie: "text/html", "application/pdf", etc...)
function DisplayModalHTML(dTitle, dWidth, dHeight, dData, obj, objType) {
    var content = "<object id='jQueryObject' type='" + objType + "' data='" + dData + "' width='100%' height='100%' />";
    jQuery(obj).empty();
    jQuery(obj).attr("title", dTitle);
    jQuery(obj).html(content);
    jQuery(obj).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        width: jQuery(window).width() * dWidth,
        height: jQuery(window).height() * dHeight,
        resizable: true,
        draggable: true,
        buttons: {

            'Close Report': function() { jQuery(this).dialog('close'); }
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: hi macgyver... this sound like a good approach... instead of an object with the data can I use like a normal div with other elements inside?

Comment: sure, just replace the X in the line "var content = X" (above) with your content.  What I have above for the <object> tag is identical to an iFrame (putting a whole page's content inside of a tag)  An object is just strict when validating XHTML.  That's really the only difference.